# How do I detected linear clusters of points in 3D data?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, cluster-analysis

I have a list of 3D points.

```
data = 
  {{57.3333, 198.833, 1}, {2.40909, 180.045, 1}, {32.1842, 170.342, 1}, 
   {195.25, 147.5, 1}, {85.7941, 143.735, 1}, {59.8333, 117.5, 1}, 
   {5.83333, 100.167, 1}, {151.5, 95., 1}, {31.3, 88.1, 1}, 
   {87.2222, 67.2222, 1}, {61., 39., 1}, ...}
```

[image]

- How can I color the points to indicate volumes of high point density?
- How can I draw lines through those clusters of points that look like linear structures, i.e., paths?

Comment: the line detection is a real challenge, google "3d hough transform line detection". I dont think there is a straightforward built in method in mathematica.

Comment: I don't know what the current state of the art is, but in the early 1990s I worked on this problem, trying to find good heuristics to solve it. I made some progress, but it turned out to be very difficult and I can't say I solved it. Maybe today machine learning could be a useful approach. One thing I learned is the problem is very sensitive to the data, so anyone who wanted to work on your problem would need your full data, not just a few points.

Comment: Thanks, ill google it. Any idea for the points density? Or some way to visualise the poits distribution? :)

Comment: Many cluster techniques tend to end up with clusters that look like ellipsoids but as you want clusters that are linear features you consider the following article: [Clustering by fast search and find of density peaks](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1242072).
Alex Rodriguez and Alessandro Laio.  Science 344, 1492 (2014).

Comment: As far as visualizing the density goes, have you seen [`ListDensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot3D.html)?

Comment: Yes, I have proved the ListDensityPlot3D, but I got an error, I think I missing something :S

`input: ListDensityPlot3D[data]`
`output: is not a valid dataset or list of datasets`

Comment: Can your data (or a much larger subset) be made available?